# Can not fetch response from web api via Jquery Ajax in some browsers

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I have this action in my Controller

```
public IHttpActionResult PostTour(Tour tour)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Tours.Add(tour);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = tour.Id }, tour);
        return Ok(tour.Id);
    }
```

and WebApiConfig is like this

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I use Jquery Ajax to send request like this

```
$(function () {

        var Tour = { 'TourName': "Tour1", 'UserName': "Mohammad223", 'Password': "Basiri@12", 'status': "0", "state": "false" };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            cache: false,


            data: (Tour),

            url: "http://localhost:53206/api/Tours",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (d) {
                data = JSON.parse(d);
                alert("Done");
            },
            error: function (result) {

            }
        });
    });
```

this function works when I use Microsoft Edge to run the Ajax Method but when I use Google Chrome or Firefox the function doesn't work properly and the alert will not be shown 
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the raised error ?

Comment: Have you looked in the developer console in Chrome or Firefox for error messages?

Comment: yes it says "Failed to load response data"

Comment: but in header status code is 200 Ok

Comment: Please test this: `data: JSON.stringify(Tour)` and this one in success block: `data = JSON.parse(d.d);`

Comment: thanks , the sent data is okay the problem is the reply that sometimes couldn't be sent back to the function

Comment: not working , I don't know why this works in Microsoft Edge but in other browsers no

Comment: which browser versions are you using to test this?

Comment: waterfox 52.0.1 and google chrome 57.0.2987.133

Comment: try adding async: false, to your ajax call

Comment: thanks brother it worked for me you have my respect

Comment: glad to help you there